# Return a single grandchild entity after filtering both parent & child (EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I've found lots of answers today that answer a portion of this requirement, but piecing them together isn't working for me.  I appreciate that it might not be possible, but my studies would indicate that it should be.

I need to return a single grandchild entity after both the parent and child entities have been filtered, e.g.

```
Parent (where user Id = 1)
  Child (where child Id = 10)
    Grandchild (where grandchild Id = 100) <-- Return this single entity
```

The purpose of the first two filters are simply for security and validity checking.  I can easily achieve the above in three separate queries, but for my learnings I'd like to make it a little more streamlined and sophisticated.

My two closest attempts are below.  I'd appreciate any narrative on why each isn't quite right, as well as the "proper" solution (if possible) please.

### Definitions

Each entity has a nullable `List<DirectChild>` property, and also an `int DirectParentId` reference navigation property.

### Filtered `Include()` plus `ThenInclude()`

```
var grandChild = await context.Parents.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(ev => ev.UserId == 1)
        .Include(ev => ev.Children!.Where(es => es.ChildId == 10))
        .ThenInclude(es => es.GrandChildren.Where(esi => esi.GrandChildId == 100))
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This is the closest I've got but rather than returning only the grandchild, it returns:

1. The first parent
2. The first child
3. The first grandchild

I tried shifting the position of `FirstOrDefaultAsync` but to no avail.

### Nested `Find()`

My studies then pointed my to using `Find` to return a single entity which also gives access to the property values.  I therefore tried this approach:

```
var grandChild = context.Parents.Where(ev => ev.UserId == 1)?
            .FirstOrDefault()?
            .Children?.Find(es => es.ChildId == 10)?.GrandChildren?
                .Find(esi => esi.GrandChildId == 100);
```

Surprisingly (to me) this returns null and I don't know why.

Can anyone please advise if its possible to return only a grandchild object but still apply the parent/child filtering?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the definitions of your entities, including the navigation properties/collections. Also add the input values you have and the result values/objects/entities you want to read.

Comment: Couldnt you start from GrandChildren instead of Parents? `var grandChild = context.GrandChildren.Where(x => x.Id == 100).Where(x => x.Parent.Id == 10 && x.Parent.Parent.Id == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in a several ways. But first regarding failed attempts.

- Filtered includes filter elements in the child collections, not their parents. Also the query returns root entities. Even though it is possible to extract the desired entity from the materialized result, it would be quite inefficient since the query will return and materialize many parent entities that you don't need. And the extraction code needed in LINQ to Objects would be the same as for the proper LINQ to Entities query.
- `Find` does not load related data, except if it is configured with `AutoInclude()`, which is not by default. Thus, accessing child collections of a materialized object will always return empty, except if lazy loading is enabled, which is also not by default. That explains why the attempt doesn't work. It could, if you enable any of the aforementioned features, but again it would be quite inefficient due to multiple db queries needed and again retrieving, materializing and tracking much more data than needed.

Now the solution(s). What you need is basically access to the "objects" inside the LINQ to Entities query in order to apply filter conditions. Note that these are not real objects, but "variables" inside the query which are used by the query translator to build the proper joins and access the corresponding table columns. What is returned depends of the final select.

All this could be done both top down using collection navigations and  `SelectMany` with filters, or bottom up using reference navigations (if you have such, which you should) with filters. Now, this can be done with LINQ method syntax by using the proper methods at the proper places, but it is much clear with query syntax and let the compiler determine the proper method calls.

So, in query syntax, we start by defining the access to the objects that we need (the code is illustrative, replace the property names with the real ones from your model):

*Top down*

```cs
from parent in context.Set<Parent>()
from child in parent.Children
from grandChild in child.Children
```

*Bottom up*

```cs
from grandChild in context.Set<GrandChild>()
let child = grandChild.Parent
let parent = child.Parent
```

The rest is one and the same - apply filters and select the final result:

```cs
where parent.UserId == 1 && child.Id == 10 && grandChild.Id == 100
select grandChild
```

And that's it. Enclose it with `()`, call the desired materialization method (`FirstOrDefault{Async}`, `ToList{Async}` etc.) and you are done. Since it is it is `IQueryable<T>`, you can also compose over it by applying additional methods like `AsNoTracking`, `Include` etc. before calling the materialization method.

Comment: Thank you; that's a very helpful answer.  In the top-down approach, VS is flagging that `parent.Children` *may be null here*, which is incredibly unlikely but not impossible if a user is refreshing an already-posted page.  In that sense, is an exception thrown in this case because items further down the query would also be null and therefore have null property values?  Just wondering how to account for this please?

Comment: `parent.Children` will *never* be null, because it is just query metadata used to build SQL query (there are no real objects/collections involved). Also it's always good to declare collection navigation properties as non nullable (collections can be empty, but should not be null), e.g. `public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; } = new HashSet<Child>();` or similar. This way you won't get warnings for both LINQ to Entities (translatable against database) and LINQ to Objects (executed against materialized objects in memory) queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the leaf item try:

```
var grandChild = await context.Parents.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(ev => ev.UserId == 1)
        .SelectMany(ev => ev.Children)
        .Where(es => es.ChildId == 10)
        .SelectMany(es => es.GrandChildren)
        .Where(esi => esi.GrandChildId == 100)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The `Include` doesn't works the way you think. It simply tells EF that when you load the parent entity also the inside collection is loaded, if you set a where collection in the lambda then only the matching child are loaded in the child collection.

So from your code you get the parent with Children collection populated only with ChildId = 10 and in it the GrandChild with GranChildId  = 100.